# Calculate number of bots in tf2

Tags: statistics

I saw a video a while back on how this game TF2 was getting an influx of bots. The player numbers on Steamcharts are logged for all games, but because of the bots in TF2, the player count is inflated.

In a normal game, there are fluctuations in player count because of day/night cycles, but these fluctuations are much less in Tf2 because the bots don't sleep.

I saw somewhere that you could use the percentage in dip of a player count compared to a game without bots to calculate an estimate of how many bots there were, but I didn't really understand the math. I've lost where that math was even so if someone knows how to do this sort of problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Tf2 player count
[image]

Dota 2 player count

[image]